# Laravel 5.6 domain and subdomains file storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have the following structure. Each of the following has a laravel installation all connected to the same database called domain. Where users table has column named user_type which differentiates users, professionals and admin

```
domain.com
professionals.domain.com
admin.domain.com
```

domain.com is for users where they can search information about professionals and articles posted by them. Hence professionals will upload images and videos too. And as the name says admin can do everything including uploading on behalf of professionals.

I know how to upload files to public or storage folder of laravel. But here i have three laravel installations with same database as my project needs this kind of setup. How can i use store images/videos/assets to a single place which can be accessed bu all three installations.

I have read about cdn and cloud storage.

Could anyone suggest me the best practice for this kind of setup.

Note: im developing on a local machine where i created virtual domains (domain.com, professionals.domain.com and admin.domain.com). So the cdn or cloud storage or any method if possible compatible with local development and live server which i have at globehost would be helpful.

I know this is not the place for advice related questions. But i feel this is the best platform where i can learn best practices from senior developers. Other platforms do not have valid answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cloud Storage is what you are looking for. One of popular Cloud Storage is AWS S3. This tutorial may give you some guides: https://wogan.blog/2017/01/04/use-amazon-s3-with-laravel-5/. 
PS. You should setup a AWS account before.

Comment: Why have you separated these out into to 3 installations instead of having them in 1 installation?

Comment: @Ross Wilson. My first version had all the three in one installation. However, now the project is large and i wanted to separate installations so that i can keep my code separate for professionals where more tools can be introduced. Moreover its easy to handle diferrent templates for each subdomain

Comment: @RossWilson Also while convertins the site to android (i mean API) Its easy for me to create android app for users and android app for professionals